# Plotting a normalized direction field

Tags: field, direction, normalize

I am trying to plot a direction field. I wish to plot a normalized vector field.
    % initialise vector field
    f=@(x,y)(2.*x-9).*(cos(y)).^2;
    A=@(x,y)x-x+1;
    B=@(x,y)f(x,y);

```
% plot the slope field
hold on
[x, y]=meshgrid(a:(b-a)/m:b , c:(d-c)/n:d);
quiver(x,y,A(x,y),B(x,y),1,'color','blue','linewidth',1.2)
[x,y] = ode45(f,[x0 b],y0);
plot(x,y,'linewidth',1,'color','black')
```

I have searched the forums and they suggest the following code

```
dy = f(x,y)
dx = ones(size(dy))
dyu = dy./sqrt(dx.^2+dy.^2)
dxu = dx./sqrt(dx.^2+dy.^2)
```

I have tried it but it does not work due to size error. Is there anyone who can suggest a modification to my code so that I can plot a normalized vector field.

Many thanks in advance!